# Unable to solve matlab expressions

Tags: matlab, expression, equation, symbolic-math

Hello I am new to matlab I have problem solving this simple expression

```
 r=10*sin(10)+10*cos(y);
```

This expression is basically a result of the simple integeral equation I coded but now  I am 
unable to solve this equation what i want is to simplify and the answer should look like

```
 r=-5.440+10*cos(y);
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1):

The [symbolic toolbox](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/products/symbolic/) can do this:

```
syms y                   % Declare symbolic variable y
r=10*sin(10)+10*cos(y);
simplify(r)              % Simplify expression
```

Note that, for precision, you will get the answer as a fraction:

```
10*cos(y) - 3062566590353811/562949953421312
```

You can use the `vpa` command to represent this as a single number:

```
vpa(simplify(r) )
```

With the result:

```
10.0*cos(y) - 5.4402111088936973004592800862156
```

Comment: Thanx.....sorrry for replying lata